# Prolog peano numbers difference/subtraction

Tags: recursion, prolog, successor-arithmetics

I am trying to work out calculating the difference for 'Peano numbers' (`Recursive definition of natural numbers represented as s(0), s(s(0)) etc.`) but I am kind of stuck with one problem.

The definition for subtraction is the following:

> `s(X) - 0 = s(X)`
>    `s(X) - s(s(X)) = 0`
>    `s(X) - s(X) = 0`
>    `s(s(X)) - s(X) = s(0)`
>    `0 - s(X) = 0`

This is my current code:

```
nat(0).
nat(s(X)) :- nat(X).

% sub/3
% Subtracts right operand from left operand and returns difference
sub(0, _, 0).
sub(X, 0, X).
sub(s(X), s(Y), X) :-
  sub(X,Y,X).
```

My thought process behind this:
Since I don't really need to recursively increase the difference I can just use the last `X` i have left after the recursion as my result.

For some reason the following question works:

> ?- sub(s(0), s(0), X).
>   X = 0 ;

But this one doesn't:

> ?- sub(s(s(0)), s(s(0)), X).
>   false.

Can anyone point out my mistake or suggest a better way to implement the sub procedure?
This might be a beginner mistake, since i really haven't done much. Sorry if that's the case.

**//EDIT**
This is how i resolved it

```
sub(X, 0, X).
sub(0, _, 0).
% not sure why I didn't test this before, thought I did.
sub(s(X), s(Y), Diff) :-
  sub(X,Y,Diff).
```

Comment: In your original definition 0 rarely occurs. Is this intended?

Comment: Well, 0 should occur when the numbers are the same, or the right one is greater than the left one. Or what do you mean?

Comment: In your original definition there was no 0 as the first argument. But then you gave a definition where it occurs as first argument, too. How do these two correspond to each other?

Comment: @false Oh, that is because by definition whenever the left operand is zero, the result has to be zero as well because there are no negative values. At least that was why i did it. I just didn't add it as a seperate rule as information since it results from the other ones.

Comment: That was exactly my point. So you are sure that they follow from the existing rules. I fail to see that `0 - 0 = 0` follows from your definition. Don't you?

Comment: @false Maybe calling the elements s(X) in my ruleset was a bit unclear then. Sorry if that was the case. s(X) € {0..+inf}

Comment: Yes, it was unclear, better use just a variable in its place. s(X) means rather {1..∞}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub(s(X), s(Y), X) :- sub(X,Y,X).
```

says that

```
You can prove that     s(X)-s(Y) = X  
if you can prove that  X-Y = X
```

which is a bit weird. There should be a third variable in there, `Z`.

Prolog tries to prove (make true)

```
sub(s(s(0)), s(s(0)), X).
```

which can be done if

```
sub(s(0),s(0),s(0)).
```

because the right-hand side of the rule is set thus by positing `X=s(0)` and `Y=s(0)` through pattern-matching the LHS.

Trying to prove this `sub(s(0),s(0),s(0))` again means using the rule (nothing else is applicable), positing `X=0`, `Y=0`, `X=s(0)`. But `X` cannot be both `0` and `s(0)`. Impasse! `false`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you have a suggestion how to improve my sub prodecure? The reason why i did it this way is, because i would have to reduce `x` and `y` recursively while adding an `s()` around the result and i couldn't get it to work.